# Disable Vertical scroll on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using `touchmove`, `touchstart` and `touchend` functions from `JQuery Mobile`. I am trying to disable vertical scroll while `touchstart` and enable it back when `touchend` is triggered. I have tried a few things:

- **Adding `overflow: hidden` to body:** This works fine for Chrome browser but doesn't work for firefox android
- Binding and Unbinding scrolling event to body when `touchstart` event fired and `touched` fired - Didn't work at all(Im sure I did it wrong). Below is the code.

Code:

```
$(document).on("touchstart", ".amount-container", function(event){
    $(".notify-cart").addClass("show");
    if(event.touches.length == event.changedTouches.length) {
        monitor = {
            x: event.touches[0].clientX,
            y: event.touches[0].clientY
        };
    }
}).on("touchend", ".amount-container", function(){
    $(".notify-cart").removeClass("show");
    $("body").removeClass("overflowhide");
    monitor = {};
}).on("touchmove mousemove", ".amount-container", function(event){
    if(Math.abs(event.changedTouches[0].clientX - monitor.x) > Math.abs(event.changedTouches[0].clientY - monitor.y)) {

    }
    else{
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
// To Prevent Scrolling while Swipe/touchmove
var touchScroll = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

I tried few other things too. Nothing worked in Firefox. Is there a better way to solve this problem. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Did you set the height of body/html to be 100%?

Comment: @MonteCristo I didn't do that.. but if an element is `overflow: hidden` it won't be scrolled.. didn't get the relationship between height and overflow property...

Comment: height of the element get adjusted to the content. If you don't define a boundary how can it "overflow"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this'll work, but try replacing

```
var touchScroll = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

with

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i tried that too.. didn't work for me :( ... could you help me with a small fiddle ...

Comment: I'll try to make one when I get home. I'm using an iPad and that just doesn't work. I can't promise I'll have time though.

Comment: Did you put a semicolon at the end? (Updating post right now.)